# Android Button: Shorten OnClick method

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

Is it possible to have multiple buttons calling the same method? I mean the parameters would be the ID of the button. My problem is that I got a really, really long switch case function and every case has the same methods. Here is my code snippet (I have shortened it):

```
public class HerkunftRind extends Activity implements   View.OnClickListener, Animator.AnimatorListener {

private static final String TAG = "HerkunftRind";
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
ImageButton myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.herkunft_rind);

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.herkunft_rinder_view_flipper);

    ImageButton imageButton = null;
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_3);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_4);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
public void setAnimationFade(int id) {
    myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(id);
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myButton, View.ALPHA, 0.5f, 1f);
    animator.setDuration(300); //ms
    animator.start();
    animator.addListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    myButton.setAlpha(1f);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1: {
            setAnimationFade(R.id.button_1);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_1_text_1);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_1_text_2);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button_2: {
            setAnimationFade(R.id.button_2);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_2_text_1);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_2_text_2);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button_3: {
            setAnimationFade(R.id.button_3);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_3_text_1);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_3_text_2);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button_4: {
            setAnimationFade(R.id.button_4);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_4_text_1);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_4_text_2);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
```

What I don't want is to define it directly in the XML file. Can I make this shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, I personally do that very often.
You can call the method in the xml layout.

i.e.:

```
<Button
     android:onClick="myMethod()"
/>
```

Mind that `myMethod()` **must** have a signature like

```
public void myMethod(View v)
```

Inside myMethod you may then want to discern **which** is the View you clicked (which can also be **heterogeneous**) and act consequentially.

Just add a `switch()` where you use `v.getId()` to determine which is the View which fired the event.

Something like this:

```
switch(v.getId())
{
    case R.id.txtPhone:
    {
        // Do something
        // ...
        break;
    }
    case R.id.txtMenu:
    {
        // Show options menu
        // ...
        break;
    }
    // ...
    default:
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I guess is OP wants to reduce the code inside `switch()` cases.

Comment: Yeah thats correct! The thing is that I don't want to define the onClick in the XML.

Comment: The reason why is that I want to separate the code from the xml file. But if there aren't any other possibilities to shorten my code, I probably have to do it that way.

Comment: The code is actually very connected to the layout. For instance, all your Views are declared there.

Comment: Okay, if I set on every butten the item: android:onClick="myMethod" there is still duplicate code in the switch case function. Have you any suggestions to improve those lines?

Comment: Which duplicate code? There should really be no duplicate code in the switch case.

Comment: Oh… I just put it in the same method ;) Thanks you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

this here is a little bit redundant:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1: {
            setAnimationFade(R.id.button_1);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_1_text_1);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_1_text_2);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.herkunft_rinder_bauer2_button: {
            setAnimationFade(R.id.button_2);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_2_text_1);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_2_text_2);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
...
```

why you just dont call setAnimationFade before the hole switch case..??

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        setAnimationFade(v.getId());
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_1: {
                setAnimationFade(R.id.button_1
```

Comment: Every time the id of the button `R.id.button_X` is changed.

Comment: I have approximately 20 pictures in a Gallery and if anyone touches them the alpha value should raise from 0.5 to 1 and a text should appear above the picture --> 20 cases in the onClick method. Can i make this shorter?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a long `onClick` method, then you could write an `onClick` listener to each button.

E.g:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


anotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```